# Does the Repository connected to a Unit of Work need to be mocked for Unit Testing in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a Unit of Work pattern along with a Repo pattern to interact with the db layer (Entity Framework in this case) and then I have dependency injection going on in the controller's constructor. My question is, so **I've mocked a IUnitOfWork which is what the controller interacts with, however, the Unit Of Work class actually accesses the repository so do I also have to mock a repository and if so, how would I implement this?** I'm trying to complete a unit test of a basic Get controller method. I've read and watched several hours of video and articles and this is what I have so far:

```
class UrlControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldReturnUrlList()
        {

            Mock<IUnitOfWork> fakeUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
            var urlController = new UrlController(fakeUnitOfWork.Object);

        urlController.Get(5); //All this is just to see if we can get thru a test.
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
```

**IRepo**

```
public interface IRepo<TEntity> where TEntity: class
    {
        TEntity Get(int id);
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        //Allows the running of lamba-style LINQ queries like the typical Entity Framework does:
        IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        void Add(TEntity entity);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

        void Remove(TEntity entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    }
```

**IUnitOfWork:**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork :IDisposable {
    IRepo<Url> Urls { get; }
    int Complete();
}
```

**UnitOfWork:**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public IRepo<Url> Urls { get; set; }
        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Urls = new Repo<Url>(_context);

        }

        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Repo:**

```
public class Repo<TEntity> : IRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public Repo(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }
        //Repositories SHOULD NOT return IQueryable because otherwise other resources may
        //Try to build queries
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using moq.

EDIT: What I'm trying to test:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var url = _unitOfWork.Urls.Get(id);
            if (url == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(url);
        }
```

Comment: Show the method under test so you know what dependencies need to be mocked for the test.

Comment: Ok you have shown a snippet of a test but haven't shown what you are trying t test. By showing what the target of the test interacts with it will help identify what needs to be mocked for the test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Target Method under test is dependent on the `IUnitOfWork` and `IRepo<Url>`. When creating unit tests you would normally mock the dependencies of the system under test so that it can be tested in isolation without having dependencies calling actual implementations (Integration Tests).

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UrlControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_With_Valid_Id_Should_Return_Url() {
        //Arrange
        var testId = 5;
        var expected = new Url { Id = testId };

        var mockRepo = new Mock<IRepo<Url>>();
        mockRepo.Setup(m => m.Get(testId)).Returns(expected);

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(m => m.Urls).Returns(mockRepo.Object);

        var sut = new UrlController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        //Act
        var actionResult = sut.Get(testId) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Url>; 

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actionResult.Content);
    }
}
```

Moq is flexible enough that you could also mock the entire dependency call so that you don't necessarily have to mock the repository if you have no need for more complicated setups.

The test would then be rewritten to

```cs
[TestClass]
public class UrlControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_With_Valid_Id_Should_Return_Url() {
        //Arrange
        var testId = 5;
        var expected = new Url { Id = testId };

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(m => m.Urls.Get(testId)).Returns(expected);

        var sut = new UrlController(mockUnitOfWork.Object);

        //Act
        var actionResult = sut.Get(testId) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Url>; 

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actionResult.Content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you _so_ much for that thorough explanation/example... I totally get it now... Basically, when you mock stuff like this, you _really_ need to get rigorous with the mocking and cover all ends/dependencies. I think the issue was that since I am new to unit testing/mocking in general, I wasn't picking up on how much was mock-able so-to-speak. Very helpful answer! Definitely one of the best answers I've received here.